# How to play youtube video on SurfaceView ?

Tags: android, video, youtube, surfaceview

I want to create an application which can play youtube videos along with local videos. The reason I used surfaceView is that I can play video in the background as an audio so the user can interact with others application. I have skipped the background service code for not making it long the post.

> My code is working fine on local videos which stored in mobile but It failed to play youtube video.

```
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        player = new MediaPlayer();

        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

           public void doPlayVideo( ){

            try {
                player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(path)); 
                player.prepareAsync();
                player.setOnPreparedListener(this);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        player.start();
        player.setLooping(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        player.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        doPlayVideo();
  }
```

Comment: This needs an video file (_eg:_ a `.mp4`), Youtube is a web page. You can extract the mp4 from Youtube HTML sources (not easy, but it's there) or find some tool that does it for you (import into your code and run functions).

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get the youtube video link form Its webpage?

Comment: Yeah just find `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` where each `url=` is the video at different quality (_eg:_ 720, 360, etc). Some parts of links are Unicode encoded like `\u0026` and some URL encoded like `%3A`. If you fix (decode) that nonsense then you have the link to MP4. Ask me if stuck at any part...

Comment: I found the "url_encoded_fmt_stream_map" and spent almost an hour to decode the link but didn't work. It would a great kindness of you If you provide an example to extract that link.

Comment: Check back in 30 mins. I'll try write some useful advice since I can't write/test Android code on this computer

Comment: Thanks for the kindness of you. Appreciate your time. :)

Comment: Sir, still waiting.

Comment: Sorry for the suspense. Not wasting your time just caught in work projects. Do you still need a guide? (or tell me where you're stuck with your current effort). I'm not going to type an essay if you already got a working solution by now.

Comment: For a link like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq2xvsVojVo ... How did you decode the link? For URL encoding in `https%3A%2F%2F` it means **%3A** = `:`  and **%2F** = `/` thus replace those `%xx` codes so it becomes `https://` etc etc... See these charts for help: [URL encodings](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) (scroll down) and also see [Unicode encodings](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) where example `U+0026` is equivalent to `\u0026` in the Youtube link. Also some have 4 chars like`%25xx` so ignore the `25` and treat as `%xx` (_eg:_ `%252C` is `%2C`)

Comment: PS: After cleaning the link, make sure you use from `https://` up to `&ip=xx.xxx.xxx.xx` then it will play (_eg:_ delete off the last part of: `&c=WEB&type=video/mp4;+codecs=%22avc1.64001F%2C+mp4a.40.2%22&itag=22&quality=hd720,`). If you don't delete then Youtube will give text "`forbidden`" (instead of video). With enough practice you'll understand how it works and how a working link looks like. Then add these checks / fixes into your code to parse & correct the URL before trying playback.